# simics-qsp-x86-6.0.53 causes pcie mcfg 0xe0100000 access error, which won't happen on 6.0.44

Tags: simics

I am porting UEFI BIOS for QSP, recently tried new release 2021.50 but found booting failed. My BIOS using pcie mcfg memory space 0xe0000000 ~ 0xf0000000 for pci device enumeration, and that would cause problem on simics-qsp-x86-6.0.53. Simics stops and simics-log shows

> 4364572099 board.mb.cpu0.mem[0][0] error   0   Access (write of 4 bytes) at 0xe0100000 where nothing is mapped.

I try to turn on ignore_unmapped_writes but it still fail.

> board.mb.cpu0.mem[0][0]->ignore_unmapped_writes=TRUE

also try adding mcfg range to board.mb.cpu0.mem[0][0] by

> board.mb.cpu0.mem[0][0].add-map board.mb.socket[0].qpi_arch.port.mcfg 0xe0000000 0x10000000

but still not working. it troubles me a lot, Please help!

the bios works without problem for simics-qsp-x86-6.0.44.

Answer (score 1):

### Analysis

**Updated twice:**

It looks like the issue here is how PCIe ECAM is enabled.  When the QSP is first started, accesses to 0xe000_0000 go to RAM. Then, the PCIe system is initialized by the UEFI (writing the PCIEXBAR register in the QPI controller), and accesses to 0xe000_0000 hit the PCI config space.  With the standard QSP UEFI, PCIEXBAR is written and the mcfg space shows up, in both QSP 6.0.42 and 6.0.53.

The implementation of PCIe in Simics has indeed changed between these two versions.  There is a new PCIe library being used in the most recent QSP versions, which has changed the internals of PCIe.  That explains the translator that gets into the memory access path in latest QSP, while there is an opaque object in the old model.  Same functionality for software, different implementation in the model.

To spot writes to PCIEXBAR in the new model, use the following Simics CLI commands:

```
simics> print-device-regs "board.mb.socket[0].qpi_arch"
```

To see the registers of the device for socket 0, which is where all the processor core are located by default.

To stop when UEFI is writing the register, do this:

```
simics> break-io device = "board.mb.socket[0].qpi_arch.bank.f1"
```

Before the breakpoint, the map of the pci_bus memory looks like this:

```
simics> board.mb.nb.pci_bus.port.mem.map
┌───────────┬───────────────────────┬──┬──────┬───────────┬───────────────────┬────┬─────┬────┐
│       Base│Object                 │Fn│Offset│     Length│Target             │Prio│Align│Swap│
├───────────┼───────────────────────┼──┼──────┼───────────┼───────────────────┼────┼─────┼────┤
│0x000a_0000│board.mb.gpu.dmap_space│  │0x0000│0x0002_0000│                   │   0│     │    │
│0x000c_0000│board.mb.shadow        │  │0x0000│0x0004_0000│board.mb.shadow_mem│   1│     │    │
│0xfec0_0000│board.mb.sb.ioapic     │  │0x0000│     0x0020│                   │  -1│    8│    │
│0xffe0_0000│board.mb.rom           │  │0x0000│0x0020_0000│                   │   0│     │    │
│  -default-│board.mb.dram_space    │  │0x0000│           │                   │    │     │    │
└───────────┴───────────────────────┴──┴──────┴───────────┴───────────────────┴────┴─────┴────┘
```

And then after the register has been written:

```
simics> board.mb.nb.pci_bus.port.mem.map
┌───────────┬─────────────────────────────────────┬──┬──────┬───────────┬───────────────────┬────┬─────┬────┐
│       Base│Object                               │Fn│Offset│     Length│Target             │Prio│Align│Swap│
├───────────┼─────────────────────────────────────┼──┼──────┼───────────┼───────────────────┼────┼─────┼────┤
│0x000a_0000│board.mb.gpu.dmap_space              │  │0x0000│0x0002_0000│                   │   0│     │    │
│0x000c_0000│board.mb.shadow                      │  │0x0000│0x0004_0000│board.mb.shadow_mem│   1│     │    │
│0xe000_0000│board.mb.socket[0].qpi_arch.port.mcfg│  │0x0000│0x1000_0000│                   │   0│     │    │
│0xfec0_0000│board.mb.sb.ioapic                   │  │0x0000│     0x0020│                   │  -1│    8│    │
│0xffe0_0000│board.mb.rom                         │  │0x0000│0x0020_0000│                   │   0│     │    │
│  -default-│board.mb.dram_space                  │  │0x0000│           │                   │    │     │    │
└───────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┴──┴──────┴───────────┴───────────────────┴────┴─────┴────┘
```

Thus, the question is really what your UEFI is writing to activate PCIEXBAR, and how that worked in the old model but not in the new model.

### After UEFI has run

After a few virtual seconds, the memory map is changed as PCIe ECAM is enabled.

New QSP:

```
simics> probe-address p:0xe000_0000
┌─────────────────────────────────────┬───────────┬─────┐
│               Target                │  Offset   │Notes│
├─────────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼─────┤
│board.mb.cpu0.mem[0][0]              │0xe000_0000│     │
│board.mb.phys_mem                    │0xe000_0000│     │
│board.mb.nb.pci_bus.port.mem         │0xe000_0000│~    │
│board.mb.nb.pci_bus.mem_space        │0xe000_0000│     │
│board.mb.socket[0].qpi_arch.port.mcfg│0x0000_0000│*    │
│board.mb.nb.pci_bus.port.cfg         │0x0000_0000│~    │
│board.mb.nb.pci_bus.cfg_space        │0x0000_0000│     │
│board.mb.nb.bridge.bank.pcie_config  │0x0000_0000│     │
└─────────────────────────────────────┴───────────┴─────┘
'*' - Translator implementing 'translator' interface
'~' - Translator implementing 'transaction_translator' interface
Destination: board.mb.nb.bridge.bank.pcie_config offset 0x0
Register:    vendor_id @ 0x0 (2 bytes) + 0
```

Old QSP (with a less capable CLI probe command):

```
simics> probe-address p:0xe0000000
┌─────────────────────────┬───────────┬─────┐
│         Target          │  Offset   │Notes│
├─────────────────────────┼───────────┼─────┤
│board.mb.cpu0.mem[0][0]  │0xe000_0000│     │
│board.mb.phys_mem        │0xe000_0000│     │
│board.mb.nb.pci_mem      │0xe000_0000│     │
│board.mb.socket_sad_f1[0]│0x0000_0000│     │
└─────────────────────────┴───────────┴─────┘
Destination: board.mb.socket_sad_f1[0] offset 0x0 - no register information available
```

### Simulation initial state

Bring up the two versions of the target and check the physical memory map.

Looking at the new QSP, before any code is run, starting from the `targets/qsp-x86/qsp-clear-linux.simics` script, I see this:

```
simics> probe-address obj = "board.mb.cpu0.mem[0][0]" p:0xe010_0000
┌─────────────────────────────┬───────────┬─────┐
│            Target           │   Offset  │Notes│
├─────────────────────────────┼───────────┼─────┤
│board.mb.cpu0.mem[0][0]      │0xe010_0000│     │
│board.mb.phys_mem            │0xe010_0000│     │
│board.mb.nb.pci_bus.port.mem │0xe010_0000│~    │
│board.mb.nb.pci_bus.mem_space│0xe010_0000│     │
│board.mb.dram_space          │0xe010_0000│     │
│board.mb.ram                 │0xe010_0000│     │
└─────────────────────────────┴───────────┴─────┘
'~' - Translator implementing 'transaction_translator' interface
Destination: board.mb.ram offset 0xe0100000


simics> board.mb.cpu0.mem[0][0].map
┌───────────┬────────────────────────┬──┬──────┬──────┬──────┬────┬─────┬────┐
│       Base│Object                  │Fn│Offset│Length│Target│Prio│Align│Swap│
├───────────┼────────────────────────┼──┼──────┼──────┼──────┼────┼─────┼────┤
│0xfee0_0000│board.mb.cpu0.apic[0][0]│  │0x0000│0x1000│      │   0│    8│    │
│  -default-│board.mb.phys_mem       │  │0x0000│      │      │    │     │    │
└───────────┴────────────────────────┴──┴──────┴──────┴──────┴────┴─────┴────┘
simics> board.mb.phys_mem.map 
┌────────────────┬────────────────┬──┬────────────────┬────────────┬──────┬────┬─────┬────┐
│            Base│Object          │Fn│          Offset│      Length│Target│Prio│Align│Swap│
├────────────────┼────────────────┼──┼────────────────┼────────────┼──────┼────┼─────┼────┤
│          0x0000│board.mb.dram_  │  │          0x0000│ 0x000a_0000│      │   0│     │    │
│                │space           │  │                │            │      │    │     │    │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼──┼────────────────┼────────────┼──────┼────┼─────┼────┤
│     0x0010_0000│board.mb.dram_  │  │     0x0010_0000│ 0xdff0_0000│      │   0│     │    │
│                │space           │  │                │            │      │    │     │    │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼──┼────────────────┼────────────┼──────┼────┼─────┼────┤
│0x0001_0000_0000│board.mb.dram_  │  │0x0001_0000_0000│0x0001_0000_│      │   0│     │    │
│                │space           │  │                │        0000│      │    │     │    │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼──┼────────────────┼────────────┼──────┼────┼─────┼────┤
│       -default-│board.mb.nb.pci_│  │          0x0000│            │      │    │     │    │
│                │bus.port.mem    │  │                │            │      │    │     │    │
└────────────────┴────────────────┴──┴────────────────┴────────────┴──────┴────┴─────┴────┘
```

I.e., that location should be hitting RAM.

You cannot just ignore unmapped writes - if you want to save some state there, you need memory or some device mapped into physical memory.  The processor cannot do much reasonable work if told to write data to locations "in the void".

So - what does your UEFI expect to be at those addresses?  How do you emulate PCIe accesses?

In Simics QSP 6.0.44, the picture looks similar:

```
simics> probe-address obj = "board.mb.cpu0.mem[0][0]" p:0xe010_0000
┌───────────────────────┬───────────┬─────┐
│         Target        │   Offset  │Notes│
├───────────────────────┼───────────┼─────┤
│board.mb.cpu0.mem[0][0]│0xe010_0000│     │
│board.mb.phys_mem      │0xe010_0000│     │
│board.mb.nb.pci_mem    │0xe010_0000│     │
│board.mb.dram_space    │0xe010_0000│     │
│board.mb.ram           │0xe010_0000│     │
└───────────────────────┴───────────┴─────┘
Destination: board.mb.ram offset 0xe0100000


simics> board.mb.cpu0.mem[0][0].map
┌───────────┬────────────────────────┬──┬──────┬──────┬──────┬────┬─────┬────┐
│       Base│Object                  │Fn│Offset│Length│Target│Prio│Align│Swap│
├───────────┼────────────────────────┼──┼──────┼──────┼──────┼────┼─────┼────┤
│0xfee0_0000│board.mb.cpu0.apic[0][0]│  │0x0000│0x1000│      │   0│    8│    │
│  -default-│board.mb.phys_mem       │  │0x0000│      │      │    │     │    │
└───────────┴────────────────────────┴──┴──────┴──────┴──────┴────┴─────┴────┘
simics> board.mb.phys_mem.map
┌────────────────┬────────────────┬──┬────────────────┬────────────┬──────┬────┬─────┬────┐
│            Base│Object          │Fn│          Offset│      Length│Target│Prio│Align│Swap│
├────────────────┼────────────────┼──┼────────────────┼────────────┼──────┼────┼─────┼────┤
│          0x0000│board.mb.dram_  │  │          0x0000│ 0x000a_0000│      │   0│     │    │
│                │space           │  │                │            │      │    │     │    │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼──┼────────────────┼────────────┼──────┼────┼─────┼────┤
│     0x0010_0000│board.mb.dram_  │  │     0x0010_0000│ 0xdff0_0000│      │   0│     │    │
│                │space           │  │                │            │      │    │     │    │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼──┼────────────────┼────────────┼──────┼────┼─────┼────┤
│0x0001_0000_0000│board.mb.dram_  │  │0x0001_0000_0000│0x0001_0000_│      │   0│     │    │
│                │space           │  │                │        0000│      │    │     │    │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼──┼────────────────┼────────────┼──────┼────┼─────┼────┤
│       -default-│board.mb.nb.pci_│  │          0x0000│            │      │    │     │    │
│                │mem             │  │                │            │      │    │     │    │
└────────────────┴────────────────┴──┴────────────────┴────────────┴──────┴────┴─────┴────┘
```

Comment: To answer your question
>what does your UEFI expect to be at those addresses? 
In real system, for those address without devices, it just simply return 0xff
>How do you emulate PCIe accesses?
Access to the PCIe mcfg memory is equal to use io type pci 0xcf8 0xcfc, So you can use 0xe0000000~0xf0000000 for pci device emulation. you can dump 0xe0000000 contents and it will show 8086xxxx, the vendor id of northbridge device.
For pcie mcfg memory range, there is no ram underneath, so the memory cycle will not go to ram. 
May be Simics can add whitelists to handle situations like this.

Comment: When doing pci device emulation, you don't know exactly where the devices are. So you have to go through all locations to find them. and that unavoidablly will fall on the unmapped locations, and In this 0xe0100000 case, it only do READ access, no WRITE operation yet. But still it been captured by Simics and been categorized as "unmapped". Sorry for "ignore_unmapped_writes=TRUE" that mis-guided you to think it is a write operation!

Comment: UEFI and OS usually have no problems finding all the config spaces of existing devices.  Reading through all of pci config seems odd to me.   UEFI should know where all the devices are, and after you set up the BARs, you know where you put the devices' control registers.

Comment: Hi jakobengblom2, thanks for the feedback. for the pci bus emulation, you can reference to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_configuration_space "BUS Emulation" section for detail. BTW 0xe0100000 is the memory mapped location for BUS 1 device 0 function 0

Comment: Sounds like something was lost in the move to the new PCIe framework used in the latest QSP.

Comment: Do you mean EMULATION or ENUMERATION?

Comment: Enumeration, sorry!

Comment: See analysis in updated answer. Check how you set PCIEXBAR

Comment: @jakovebfblom2 the statement is wrong-"the question is really what your UEFI is writing to activate PCIEXBAR, and how that worked in the old model but not in the new model.". Only a READ to location 0xe0100000 already caused the trap, no WRITE yet!

Comment: That makes no sense?  To get mcfg memory-mapped you code has to do some write via IO to the PCi bridge configuration.

Comment: Do read first to make sure device is exist, then do write to configure. In QSP case, BUS 1 device 0 function 0 (0xe0100000) has no device, so read this location will return 0xffffffff. BIOS or OS will look for next location BUS 1 device 1, BUS 1 device 2, ..... Scan and configure all device.  Simics should not trap for the READ!

Comment: In order to get the memory-mapped reads to work, you have to first write the PCIEXBAR register of the bridge.  Only then can you probe the memory-mapped space for devices.  PCI comes up without that area mapped, and the BIOS must write to the register (via the IO path) before touching the mcfg memory.  Do check the early init code of the BIOS.

Comment: After digging deeper into the BIOS source, I found BIOS will do a write first to all the possible device slot locations, even they are empty. this according to PCI Express Base Specification, 2.2.6.2. A config write is required in order for the device to re-capture the Bus number. I decide to remove this step to avoid trigger QSP simulator's fault alert!

Comment: Which edition of the specification?  In the specs that I have (PCIe base 3.0 and 5.0) 2.2.6.2 is "Transaction descriptor - Transaction ID field".

What BIOS are you running?  I did not expect a Tianocore/EDK-II UEFI would be doing that. 

But - those memory accesses should still be hitting RAM and not be unmapped. So there is something else going on as well.  Did you customize the QSP setup in any way?

Comment: In specification, please look for description "Functions must capture the Bus and Device Numbers....". and I am porting AXX bios for QSP. I think QSP is a very good environment for developing software related bios features. For the setup, I only pick items as need for now